# How to kill number of processes in cpanel

Tags: node.js, process, cpanel

I am running a node js backend in cpanel server and it was working good before but when today I upload my latest updated files to file manager and start the node js app again it gives me error while run this command `node index.js` that the port is currently using. I change the port multiple time now the process of my cpanel is reached max limit 175/175 and now i can't access the terminal. When I go to terminal in cpanel it gives me this `cagefs_enter: Unable to fork`

Now please anyone tell me how can i kill all process which i start with `node index.js` this command

[image: Picture showing all process]

all my running processes